# Cannot reference InputsActions from my script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to reference my InputActions panel from my script, but it gives me an error: The tupe or namespace "PlayerControls" could not be found(are you missing an using directive or an assembly reference?). This is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public CharacterController controller;
public float speed = 6f;
float turnsmoothvelocity;
public float turnsmoothtime;
public Transform cam;
PlayerControls controls;
Vector2 move;
void Awake()
{
controls = new PlayerControls();
controls.Gameplay.moverse.performed += ctx => move = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
controls.Gameplay.moverse.canceled += ctx => move = Vector2.zero;
}
void OnEnable()
{
controls.Gameplay.Enable();
}
void OnDisable()
{
controls.Gameplay.Disable();
}
```

Comment: Well what is `PlayerControls` and where is it implemented?

Comment: PlayerControls is the InputActions asset